# How to concatenate strings in multiple lists at the same index

Tags: string, python-3.x, string-concatenation, series

I have 3 `series`, each has equivalent length, I converted them to 3 `list`. I want to concatenate the strings in the lists at the same index, and put the concatenated strings in another list. How to do that? e.g. `list1[0] + list2[0] + list3[0]` for each index `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> l2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> l3 = ["!", "?", "."]
>>> [''.join(item) for item in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
['a1!', 'b2?', 'c3.']
```

---

> what if the l1, l2, l3 are in a list l, and I don't know how many elements in l, how to do the concatenation

In this case, you can just *unpack* the list with sublist to the `zip()` function arguments:

```
>>> l = [l1, l2, l3]
>>> [''.join(item) for item in zip(*l)]
['a1!', 'b2?', 'c3.']
```

Comment: what if the `l1`, `l2`, `l3` are in a list `l`, and I don't know how many elements in `l`, and I want to concatenate the strings in each element, how to do the concatenation. thx

Comment: @daiyue okay, updated with a sample - hope I understood the problem correctly.